# Generic Table Model

Tags: java, swing, generics, instantiation, tablemodel

I wanted to create a flexible table model where it's list variable type may differ upon it's instantiation. I extends AbstractTableModel class, here is the code :

```
package models;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class GenericTableModel < T > extends AbstractTableModel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List< T > list = new ArrayList< T >();
    private int columns;

GenericTableModel(int columns){
    this.columns = columns;
}

public void updateAll(Collection<T> collection){
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(collection);
    fireTableDataChanged();
}

public T getCell(int index){
    return list.get(index);
}

public void setData(List list){
    this.list = list;
    fireTableDataChanged();     
}

public void insert(T data){
    list.add(data);
    fireTableRowsInserted(getRowCount() - 1, getRowCount() - 1);
}

public void delete(int index){
    list.remove(index);
    fireTableRowsDeleted(index, index);
}

public void update(int index, T data){
    list.set(index, data);
    fireTableRowsUpdated(index, index);
}

public T select(int index){
    return list.get(index);
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columns;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    String databaseURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/perkuliahan";
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try{
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, "root", "");
        statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        T className = null;
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from " + className.getClass().getName());
        while(resultSet.getRow()!=rowIndex){
            resultSet.next();
        }
        return resultSet.getObject(columnIndex);
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlException){
        return sqlException.getMessage();
    }
    finally{
        try{
            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException sqlException){
            return sqlException.getMessage();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column){
    String databaseURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/perkuliahan";
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try{
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, "root", "");
        statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        T className = null;
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from " + className.getClass().getName());
        ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData;
        resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        return resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(column);
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlException){
        return sqlException.getMessage();
    }
    finally{
        try{
            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException sqlException){
            return sqlException.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

}

But, once I declared it, it shows error message :

```
package forms;

import models.GenericTableModel;
import pojo.Mahasiswa;

public class MahasiswaForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form MahasiswaForm
 */
public MahasiswaForm() {
    initComponents();
    GenericTableModel<Mahasiswa> tableModel = new GenericTableModel<Mahasiswa>();
}
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong ? I need this for school assignment, thank you.

Comment: What error message do you see? And you would **never** want to create a table model that uses a JFrame as its data type. Never. The generic type should be of the type of data that the JTable holds, as in model data, not view types.

Comment: Also your code breaks Swing threading rules, by doing all the database calls on the event thread. You don't want your table's data to come directly from the database, but rather should have it held by some local connection.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, My apologies, I forgot to fill the bracket with integer value, I was supposed to type `new GenericTableModel<Mahasiswa>(4);` and set the constructor in GenericTableModel Class public. But, about this Swing threading rules, can you explain the detail or give me a link that explains it ? Seems like I'm missing a lot of stuff...I don't know what threading is...thank you so much for your help

Comment: Your bigger problem is to use Mahasiswa as your generic type. Why would you want to do that as it makes no sense? The model should reflect the table's data and should not concern itself with the view. For Swing threading, read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, Here is the case :
I would like to create more than one forms, each form have their own table. Each table views different data, this one shows Mahasiswa / CollegeStudent data, the second shows MataKuliah / Courses and the last one shows Dosen / Instructor data. If I create 3 classes that represent each reference data types (CollegeStudents, Courses and Instructor), I thought it would be a waste of time, which is why I decided to make a GenericTableModel that may represents those classes in a single class. Those 3 classes are POJO from Perkuliahan / College database.

Comment: You're still doing it all wrong if you're trying to pass in a view object. Again, you should use the datatype that the table model holds as its generic type. Please let me know what about this confuses you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/). It is an example of a generic TableModel. You will need to extend this class and implement the getValueAt() and setValueAt() methods for your POJO.

You should NOT have database code in the `getValueAt()` method. This method is called frequently whenever the table needs to render a cell. Therefore this code should be very efficient. Same comment for the `getColumnClass()` method although this will not be an issue if you use the RowTableModel.

For a completely generic solution so that you need do write a custom TableModel you can also look at the `Bean Table Model`